# How to use redirect users to different sub-website based on user information based on symfony3

Tags: symfony-cmf, symfony-3.2

In my system, it will be multiple front-end portal for consumer.
All the different portals contains same logic but different css style only.

For example:

- Portal Default : www.myweb.com
- Portal A : a.myweb.com

And a user belongs to portal A could access the system from both default portal and A portal.

If the user login the default portal, just redirect him to Portal A.

I just wonder if there is an easy way to implement this with Symfony 3.

Meanwhile I am thinking about the CMS for these portals.

It seems that CMF only support symfony 2.

I am not sure if it could fit symfony 3.

As all the portals use the same content, the CMS only maintain default portal contents.

Thank you for your time and please kindly share your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently integrated Symfony CMF 2.0.0 with Symfony 3.3 project. It works, although most of its bundles are deprecated or poorly maintained.
Also I encountered an issue that having multiple tree roots (for each subdomain for example) in Symfony CMF is [not implemented](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf/wiki/Multi-Domain-Support)

Besides Symfony CMF there are some other Symfony and PHP based content management solutions:

- Sylius (ecommerce solution)
- Drupal 8
- eZPublish 5
- Bolt CMS
- October CMS
- PageKit
- Sulu CMS